# Unable to load ActivityHistory for shared activities in APEX

Tags: activities, shared-activities

I'm using APEX to load ActivityHistory records for Contacts. However, in an org using shared activities I find that my query only returns records for which a contact is the primary 'WhoId' -- not the other activities to which it is related as a secondary.

Strangely enough I *am* able to get all the records when running the exact same code in the Execute Anonymous window. The Query Editor also returns all the records.

Here's my test code:

```
Id contactId = ....;
Contact contact = [SELECT Id, (Select WhoId,Id FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC, LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 499) FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contactId];
System.assertEquals(2, contact.ActivityHistories.size());
```

Where `contactID` refers to a contact with two shared activities for which it is not the primary 'WhoId'.

The assertion fails when run from an APEX class (with or without sharing), but passes when run in the Execute Anonymous window.

I tried calling the APEX class from a unit test (with `seeAllData=true`) as well as from the Execute Anonymous window -- both fail.

Am I missing something? Or is this a 'limitation' in what you can do from APEX?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "secondary contact". If you have custom lookup on Task/Event then it'd fall under another related list, right? Also - as stupid as it sounds - try playing with different API versions (test your select in workbench.developerforce.com for example). There's some magic around EventAttendee & EventRelation so maybe you have to adjust the API version of your class to get this secondary stuff? https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm

Comment: Secondary contact is a contact that shows as '+1' in the user interface when shared activities are enabled. In the API it is a contact linked to a Task/Event through a TaskRelation/EventRelation, but not listed as the WhoID for the Task/Event. Thanks for the workbench suggestion -- I will try that out

Comment: I've noticed this, too. While it's not documented that I could find, it seems you need to query both activity history and event relations.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous window executes everything in system mode whereas the APEX which you are running inside the Salesforce UI obeys all the sharing rule. Try to use

```
without sharing
```

keyword in your class and see how it works. And in your test class, create a user and use RunAs to test it.

Comment: Thanks, but I already used without sharing -- same result. Also, I ran the APEX class from the anonymous window, and it still fails to find the shared activities

Comment: some kind of sharing rule that affects the test running user to see the activities data. Can you check the profile and access privileges for the user trying to run the test case?

Comment: I did all testing from standard System Administrator profile.

Comment: I don't think there are any special sharing rules or the like set up -- it's a pretty standard org. But is there any particular place I should be looking?